# When wielding a reach weapon can you use armored spikes to make Attacks of Opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

Something showed up in [Harry Potter and the Natural 20](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8096183/44/Harry-Potter-and-the-Natural-20) (a HP & D&D 3.5e fanfiction) and I was wondering about application in pathfinder: When wielding a two handed [reach](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-reach) weapon (or 1 handed with shield), can you can use [armored spikes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spiked-armor) to make Attacks of Opportunities against foes nearby?

The Reach quality for weapons only specifies that you "can't use *it* against an adjacent foe." And the Spiked Armor quality specifies that you can use it as part of a grapple, or as a separate attack.

**Edit:** Just finished that page of the HP fanfic, and it mentions a note at the end that the above technique doesn't work in pathfinder according to an FAQ. However, that's after the entire D&D tip section, so it could be referring specifically to using a two handed weapon and TWF abilities to wield the armor spike as an offhand weapon. Bonus: does anyone know what FAQ is being referred to?

Comment: Is the question about using armored spikes for your reach attack (very strangely, not that I'm suggesting it's possible), or is it about whether you can use your armor spikes against adjacent enemies whilst still being able to use your reach weapon against farther ones? I'm not clear on what trick shows up in this chapter.

Comment: The latter. It's about using normal armor spikes for close up enemies in conjunction with a normal reach weapon (i.e. not reach spikes, that would be... strange)

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, you can

You are wielding a weapon that threatens adjacent squares, and using both hands on your polearm does not interfere with the use of the armor spikes. Thus, you can make attacks with them and threaten the squares they reach.

Note that there is usually a hefty gold cost to doing this, as you have to pay for two weapons instead of one. Typically a reach-weapon-user’s armor spikes lag quite a bit behind his main polearm in terms of special abilities.