# Can I remove one claw from a Two Handed Weapon at the end of each turn, so I can make Attacks of Opportunity with the claw?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

My character is a Tengu Gunslinger armed with a Musket, a two-handed ranged weapon. He also has a number of Natural Weapons — two Claws and a Bite — which can be used for primary Natural Attacks.

As pointed out in [this question/answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31940/when-wielding-a-reach-weapon-can-you-use-armored-spikes-to-make-attacks-of-oppor), whilst he is carrying his Musket in both hands (errr... claws?), he would still threaten the squares within 5' of himself with his Bite Attack and is capable of making Attacks of Opportunity.

However, is it possible to just remove one hand from the Musket at the end of each turn, leaving a Claw free to threaten and make Attacks of Opportunity?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes

As [this FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qda) mentions, a creature can take a free action to remove one hand from of a two-handed weapon. When a creature has removed one hand from a two-handed weapon, it can't wield that two-handed weapon, but the creature can do whatever it wants with that now-empty hand, and that includes making attacks (and attacks of opportunity) with that limb's claw.

(The game doesn't care that the two-handed weapon is a projectile weapon or a pole arm or a greatsword.)