# Can a PC with a reach weapon attack a tiny creature moving into his square?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, reach

Tiny creatures can move in an enemy's square but they provoke an AoO.

> Very Small Creature
>
> A Fine, Diminutive, or Tiny creature can move into or through an occupied square. The creature provokes attacks of opportunity when doing so.

And

> Reach: You use a reach weapon to strike opponents 10 feet away, but you can’t use it against an adjacent foe.

Can I make a attack against a creature moving into my square? I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Big and Little Creatures in Combat**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Big-And-Little-Creatures-In-Combat) on **Tiny, Diminutive, and Fine Creatures**, in part, says, "You can attack into your own square if you need to, so you can attack such creatures [i.e. the ones that provoke for moving into your square] normally." However, when a creature's armed with a reach weapon, it's typically not able to attack normally: The [reach](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/weapons/#wpn-quality-reach) quality of many weapons says, "You use a reach weapon to strike opponents 10 feet away, but you can’t use it against an adjacent foe." This includes foes that move from adjacent (like from a square next to your space) to even adjacenter (like into your space).

**Make that attack of opportunity despite that pesky polearm:** A typical Medium creature that's armed with a reach weapon and that's also wearing [spiked armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spiked-armor/)/[armor spikes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/armor-spikes/) (or similar weapon) or that possesses the [Improved Unarmed Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-unarmed-strike-combat) feat (therefore, in both cases, also threatening its adjacent squares) *can* make an attack of opportunity against a little creature that attempts to enter its space, but it makes that attack of opportunity with the spiked armor or the unarmed strike rather than the reach weapon.

---

***Note:** You may also be interested in answers to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31940/8610)*

Answer (score 7):

### No.

You make AoO when a creature leaves one of your 'controlled' squares - i.e. those squares that you can strike with a weapon. Which, in case of 'reach' weapon are 10 feet away.

Once it had left them - you can't make AoO against them.

Comment: Are you saying that the rules text for very small creatures (*The creature provokes attacks of opportunity when doing so.*) isn't adding any new conditions for AoOs, just saying that you can make them as normal? e.g. with a non-reach weapon, if one moves from 5 ft away from you to 10 ft away from you, into the same square as another creature, you could make an AoO, regardless of there being another creature there.

Comment: And that moving into a creature's own square would normally count as leaving its threatened area if it has a non-reach weapon?  Can non-reach weapons normally attack creatures that share your square in pathfinder 1e or not?  If not it's just reminding you that moving into your space could provoke an AoO for that reason?

Comment: @PeterCordes - you forget about option of 5-foot step that exists in PF, moving with which doesn't normally provoke an AoO. Addition of 'the creature provokes an opportunity attack, while doing so' overrules it, due to being case of 'specific' over 'general'.